# Prove integrable function by partition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x=1/n ,\text{ $n$ is an integer }\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

a) Prove that $f$ is integrable

b) Show that $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$

My attempt: Let $P=\{0,1/n, 1/n+1/n^2,1/n+2/n^2,\ldots,1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$.

$l_i= \inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]\}=0$, hence $L(f, P) =0$

$u_i = \sup\{f(x)\mid x\in[x_i-1,x_i]\}=1$, hence $U(f,P) =\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i\triangle x_i$

I do not know how to argue to get $U(f, P) -L(f, P)<\varepsilon $

Answer (score 1):

$a)$: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. choose the partition $\mathcal{P} = \{0,\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n},\cdots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$ such that $n > \dfrac{3}{\epsilon}$, then:

$U(\mathcal{P}) - L(\mathcal{P})= (1-0)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-0\right)+ (1-0)\left(\dfrac{2}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)+ (0-0)\left(\dfrac{3}{n}-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots + 0 + (1-0)\left(1-\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)= \dfrac{3}{n}< \epsilon \Rightarrow \text{ f is integrable}$.

$b)$: With the given partition $\mathcal{P}$ above, using the right Riemann sum $R_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n M_i\triangle x_i= 1\cdot \dfrac{1}{n} + 1\cdot \dfrac{1}{n} + 0+0\cdots + 0+1\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}=\dfrac{3}{n}\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} R_n = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{3}{n} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the answer. How to know that P works ? the length of the subintervals need not to be equal, right? by choosing this partition, we have $\triangle x_i=1/n$ for any subinterval.One more thing: It seems we solve everything to down on 3/n, then let $3/n <\varepsilon$. From that, at the beginning of the argument, we "let" $\varepsilon >0$ and ... such that $n> 3/\varepsilon$ .Am I right? I am so frustrating with myself when seeing everybody work smoothly while I am struggling in defining n

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ONE partition. What integrable means is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition, $P_{\epsilon}$ such that $U(f,P_{\epsilon})-L(f,P_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$.

Hint: center partitions around all the $\frac{1}{n}$ and make them smaller, depending on $\epsilon$.

Comment: I know that it works with any partition and any test points. So, why not that partition? How to argue since $L (f, P_\varepsilon )=0$?

Comment: You know that what works with any partition? You only have ONE partition, you need an infinite family of partitions, each depending on $\epsilon$. @user73195

Comment: I sounds like we speak in different languages. :) I don't get what you mean. I am sorry.

Comment: The statement of integrability is the following: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition, $P_{\epsilon}$, such that $U(f,P_{\epsilon})-L(f,P_{\epsilon}))<\epsilon$. Do you understand this statement?

Comment: yes, so all we need is only 1 specific partition satisfies the condition, right?

Comment: Incorrect. You will (almost) always need infinitely many partitions! Each one depends on $\epsilon$. This is exactly like limits involving sequences. "For all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that...". The $N$ DEPENDS on $\epsilon$, just like the partition depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22725/discussion-between-user73195-and-avid19).